# Not able to run Rails Migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I ran `rails g scaffold task message:string` but I keep getting this error:

```
<internal:/Users/rosali/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require': dlopen(/Users/rosali/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/puma-5.6.6/lib/puma/puma_http11.bundle, 0x0009): symbol not found in flat namespace '_SSL_get1_peer_certificate' - /Users/rosali/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/puma-5.6.6/lib/puma/puma_http11.bundle (LoadError)
    from <internal:/Users/rosali/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from /Users/rosali/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    from /Users/rosali/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/puma-5.6.6/lib/puma.rb:14:in `<main>'
    from <internal:/Users/rosali/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from <internal:/Users/rosali/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from /Users/rosali/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    from /Users/rosali/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/rosali/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Users/rosali/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `block in require'
    from /Users/rosali/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `each'
    from /Users/rosali/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `require'
    from /Users/rosali/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler.rb:187:in `require'
    from /Users/rosali/pprojects/react-projects/todo-list-api/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
    from <internal:/Users/rosali/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from <internal:/Users/rosali/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from /Users/rosali/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    from /Users/rosali/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.6/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:22:in `require_application!'
    from /Users/rosali/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.6/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:14:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    from /Users/rosali/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.6/lib/rails/commands/generate/generate_command.rb:21:in `perform'
    from /Users/rosali/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/rosali/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/rosali/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/thor-1.2.2/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/rosali/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.6/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
    from /Users/rosali/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.6/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
    from /Users/rosali/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    from <internal:/Users/rosali/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from <internal:/Users/rosali/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
    from /Users/rosali/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Tried bundle update --bundler and gem update --system but I'm still getting the same issue.

Comment: How did you install Ruby and what version of OpenSSL do you have installed? The error message looks like an incompatibility issue between Ruby and OpenSSL. AFAIK Ruby 3.0 is only compatible with OpenSSL 1.1.1. I suggest uninstalling Ruby and OpenSSL and then installing OpenSSL 1.1.1 and re-installing Ruby.

Comment: You appear (from the error msg) to be using rvm to manage ruby, but your "site ruby" is also being used. You should delete your site ruby. You don't need it when you use rvm and it's leading to problems.

Comment: If you're using Homebrew, it's possible a library used to build your Ruby got "cleaned" and now the dependency isn't available. It's worth doing a `brew update` to check for the latest version, `brew upgrade` where appropriate, then rebuild your RVM Ruby.

Comment: This may be your problem I think https://www.lewuathe.com/ruby-build-failure-with-openssl3.html